# How to reset the port for Java.exe process

Tags: java, blueprism

I am currently setting BluePrism resourcepc service in my VM and it always shows the status 'Offline'. After the deep analysis, we found that BluePrism using 8181 port which is already being used by the process java.exe.

Hence if i kill the java.exe process through task manager, issue is resolved and everything is working fine however if i restart the VM, then the java process accessing port 8181.

Can someone help me how to change the port for java process?

Comment: Java itself doesn't use port 8181 for anything I know of. I'm pretty sure this is some application, that is incidentally written in java. So check that particular application's documentation to find out how to change the port it listens on.

Comment: Yes. Java itself uses no ports by default. You have something else running, which depends on Java. You can't change Java. You change that program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BluePrism root folder a program called automate.exe which you can use to set all kinds of preferences for BluePrism. Try to set the port with this:

```
 automate.exe /resourcepc /port "new port" /public
```

So as an example:

```
 automate.exe /resourcepc /port 1234 /public
```

Comment: What is automate?

Comment: It's a part of BluePrism, you can use it to alter certain settings. Thought that would be selfexplanatory else i would've told the guy to download it seperately. Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: It's fine, but would be useful as part of the answer. Otherwise it's not clear how this answers any questions about Java